# How to add uncertainty to tics in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some experimental data using gnuplot and I need to include data uncertainty in tics' labels. I've figured out that I can manually change every label to "200.0" from "200", but I'm almost sure that there is an easier method. I do hope for your help. :)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far so that we can offer suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. I understand it like this

```
$data <<EOD
120 20 250 30 
160 20 190 40 
200 30 300 23
280 15 260 15
340 25 190 40
EOD

plot $data us 1:3:4:xtic(sprintf("%.1f +/- %.1f", $1, $2)) w err pt 7
```

[image]

See `help xticlabel` (in contrast to `xtics`).

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Thing, I was looking for, was simple x,y format. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer! Your solution looks really pretty. :)